# Pass object between classes bad practice?

Tags: c#, oop, parameter-passing

I am currently developing an IRC bot in C#. I have a IRC class containing information about the IRC server(IP,Port,Channel,Nick) and methods like send and read. Whenever I receive any information from the server i pass it to a message handler, which checks if it is a command by using a directory like shown below

```
private Dictionary<string, ICommandState> _commandList;
```

I am using gof state pattern to create new commands. One command I have is `PingCommand` this command wants to write "PONG" out to the IRC server as a respond to "PING". I have drawn er quick class diagram [image: here]

So here is my question/problem. I want the PingCommand(and properly other commands too) to know about the IRC object created in the "MainClass". One way to do this would be to just pass it to the constructor of the MessageHandler and then the MessageHandler would pass it to the PingCommand, but i feel like that would be bad design as the MessageHandler doesnt need the IRC object.

Another way would be to just make the IRC class static but im not too sure if thats a good way to do it?

The last solution(and the one I use atm) I could come up with was to create another class called CommandProvider which basicly sets up the Dictionary like this:

```
    public CommandProvider(IIRC irc)
    {
        CommandList = new Dictionary<string, ICommandState>();
        CommandList.Add("PING",new PingCommand() {Irc = irc});
        CommandList.Add("376",new Command376() { Irc = irc });
        CommandList.Add("366",new Command366() { Irc = irc });
    }
```

and then pass it to the messageHandler, but I am still not too sure if this is a good way to do it?

I hope you guys can give me some suggestions on how to proceed

Comment: Google "c# dependency injection".

Comment: I am not quite sure how that will fix my problem?

Comment: I think I am using that already?

This is from the main class:
IIRC myIRC = new IRC();

.
IMessageHandle mHandler = new MessageHandle(new CommandProvider(myIRC));